# Clean Inner Class implementing Runnable

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, runnable

I have got a Class for a CustomView that has to inner Classes, both implement Runnable to do a Job in a separate Thread.

```
public class ValueSelector extends LinearLayout{

.....

private class AutoIncrementer implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (plusButtonIsPressed) {
            incrementValue();
            mHandler.postDelayed(new AutoIncrementer(), REPEAT_INTERVAL_MS);
        } else {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}

private class AutoDecrementer implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (minusButtonIsPressed) {
            decrementValue();
            mHandler.postDelayed(new AutoDecrementer(), REPEAT_INTERVAL_MS);
        } else {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
}
```

How to clean them up properly?
Do they get Destroyed automatically when the Activity hosting those CustomViews gets destroyed?

Cheers

Comment: They never get "destroyed". The will get garbage collected some time after they become unreachable, same as any other object instance in Java. In this case, that'll likely be some time after their thread stops running.

Comment: normal inner class include implicit reference to top class so when activity destroyed still reference will be exist with that and gc will not clean this problem you need to make inner class static and also use weakreference and also use thread handler for long running jobs and runOnUiThread method u can update your ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not get destroyed  causing a memory leak, as your thread will have a strong reference to your view, and hence your activity.

Make the inner class static and hold weak reference to variables you need in run method.

Second thing you can do is interrupt your thread , when you view get detached from the window and have check in the run method if thread got interrupted or not, though not necessary if your thread is not doing too much work.

Here is what your runnable should look like

```
private static class AutoDecrementer implements Runnable {

    AutoDecrementer (ValueSelector valueSelector ){
       this.weakRef = new WeakReference<>(valueSelector);
    }      


    @Override
    public void run() {
         ValueSelector valueSelector =  (ValueSelector )weakRef.get();
         if(valueSelector == null){
            return ;
          }  

        if (valueSelector.minusButtonIsPressed) {
            valueSelector .decrementValue();
            valueSelector .mHandler.postDelayed(new AutoDecrementer(), REPEAT_INTERVAL_MS);
        } else {
            valueSelector.mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

I have not checked for any errors.

Comment: How does it look in Code? I have put the inner Classes static but then nearly everything needs to become static. Also the boolean used in run() methods can't be a WeakReference etc Cheers

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Thanks!
What could be the errors you mentioned btw?
Cheers

Comment: meant do not copy and paste, use the idea, I am glad it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

No, it will cause error if Activity is destroyed while timer event is still pending. To avoied that, use WeakReference to some object, decrementing value.
But, generally it is  bad practice - to mix UI and some ligic, because it is difficule to test. Consider using rxJava library, this will look like

```
 Subscriptioin s = Observable.just(100, TimeUnit.Milliseconds)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.computation())
.subscribe(t -> decrementValue());
```

in your onPause() method cancel that actioin by

```
if (s != null && !s.inUnsubscribed()) { 
s.unsubscribe(); 
s = null; 
}
```